# Как написать древовидную структуру отступов html элементов

Tags: javascript

Есть структура код ниже.

Надо реализовать древовидную структуру отступов html элементов.

То есть:У номера `1` не должен быть отступов а у `1.1` 10 пикселей `1.1.1` 20 пикселей `1.2` опять 10 пикселей и т.д.

Все что у меня получилось внизу.

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");

[...links].reduce((acc, val) => {
  let counter = 0;
  if (acc.textContent[counter] === val.textContent[counter]) {
    if (acc.style.paddingLeft === "10px") {
      val.style.paddingLeft = "20px";
    } else {
      val.style.paddingLeft = "10px";
    }
  }
  return (acc = val);
});
```

```css
a {
  list-style: none;
}
.doc-menu .nav-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #616670;
}
```

```html
<nav id="doc-menu" class="nav doc-menu flex-column sticky">
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#section-2">1 aa 5</a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#section-3">1.1 bbb</a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#section-4">1.1.1 addasdasd </a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#section-4">1.1.1.1 test </a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#section-5"
    >2 some</a
  >
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#section-6">2.1 bulso</a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#section-9">2.1.1 bazuk</a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#section-13">2.2 zept</a>
</nav>
```

Тут я понимаю что надо удваивать результат переменной пиксели но не понимаю как это правильно сделать чтобы при добавлении `1.1.1.1` (или еще больше чисел) все работало без дополнительных проверок на ифы.
Попробовал еще так написать также неудачно.

```
[...links].reduce((acc, val) => {
  let counter = 0;
  let px = 10;
  if (acc.textContent[counter] === val.textContent[counter]) {
    const accPad = +acc.style.paddingLeft.split("px")[0];
    const valPad = +val.style.paddingLeft.split("px")[0];
    if (accPad > valPad) {
      val.style.paddingLeft = px * 2 + "px";
    } else {
      val.style.paddingLeft = px + "px";
    }
  }
  return (acc = val);
});
```

**Upd**: Как видите отступ блока `1.1.1.1` эквивалентен отступу блока `1.1` что не правильно.

Comment: Вообще такие вещи делаются через `ul->li` и не надо заморачиваться с падингами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать таким образом. Просто бьём значение по пробелу и считаем кол-во символов!

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");

[...links].forEach(val => {
  const current = val.textContent.split(' ').shift();
  val.style.paddingLeft += `${(current.length - 1)* 10}px`;
});
```

```css
a {
  list-style: none;
}
.doc-menu .nav-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #616670;
}
```

```html
<nav id="doc-menu" class="nav doc-menu flex-column sticky">
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#section-2">1 aa 5</a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#section-3">1.1 bbb</a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#section-4">1.1.1 addasdasd </a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#section-5"
    >2 some</a
  >
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#section-6">2.1 bulso</a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#section-9">2.1.1 bazuk</a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#section-13">2.2 zept</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: O_o .Можно комментарии к коду пожалуйста? (+1)

Comment: @Demon__ ну с помощью `split` мы бьём строку на массив, тем самым под индексом 0 у нас цифры, остальное буквы. Далее `shift` берёт первый элемент массива. Далее с помощью length - 1 определяем смещение ну и умножаем на 10

Comment: Огромное спасибо.

Comment: @Demon__ пожалуйста!

Comment: @Demon__ у Вас у каждого элемента по умолчанию padding стоит. уберите их! js не получается их заменить

Comment: Да исправил спасибо